# Splitting string with similar starting pattern

Tags: java

So, I've been trying to split something I'm reading from a file. But everything that I've tried does not give me only the part that I want. 
What I have as string is this:

```
Scenario:
Bunch of stuf here
Just typing stuff for the example...

Scenario:
More stuff here
A lot more stuff here
XX123
```

I want to get everything from **'Scenario:'** to **'XX123'**
Like this:

```
Scenario:
More stuff here
A lot more stuff here
XX123
```

The file that I'm reading from have a lot of those **'Scenarios:'** and using Pattern from java doesn't give me only the part that I want. Instead it gives from the first **'Scenario:'** it finds until **'XX123'**

I also tried to use *StringUtils.substringBetween*, same result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to delete scenario that does not end with XX123?

Comment: @Goion no, I want to get only the Scenario that has XX123, just copy it

Comment: What is "XX123"? Could it be 12323? or just XX123? or XX124, XX125... so on? or could be AB122? I just wanna be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old-fashioned way to do it would look something like this:

```java
String inputText;

String END_MARKER = "XXX123";

int indexOfEnd = inputText.indexOf(END_MARKER);
// search in reverse
int indexOfScenario = inputText.lastIndexOf("Scenario", indexOfEnd);

String result = inputText.substring(indexOfScenario, 
    indexOfEnd + END_MARKER.length());
```